# Byte-to-binary conversion function

Tags: c, converting, bitwise

My implementation of a binary-to-bits converting function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned char *return_byte (unsigned char source)
{
    static unsigned char byte[CHAR_BIT];
    unsigned char *p = byte, i;

    for(i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++)
        p[i] = '0' + ((source & (1 << i)) > 0);

    return p;
}



int main(void)
{
    unsigned char val = 200;

    printf("Value:\t%i\nBinary:\t%s", val, return_byte(val));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Value:  200
> Binary: 00010011
> ```

Comment: I just received an idea for optimization. Make the function understands of endians. But I will leave this to the reviewers.

Comment: You could provide a self-review.

Comment: Can I actually do that?

Comment: Yes, you can - especially if it dramatically improves the code.

Comment: Your output is (of course) little-endian. That's not the conventional way to write numbers. We usually write big-endian style even in non-decimal bases. 200 is 'two hundred' not 'two'. I would normally read binary '00010011' as nineteen (decimal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `return_byte` doesn't tell much what the function is intended to do. `btoa` would be more in line with C naming convention (akin to `itoa`)
- A `p` variable is pretty much useless. Consider

  ```
  static unsigned char byte[CHAR_BIT];
  unsigned char i;

  for(i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++)
      byte[i] = '0' + ((source & (1 << i)) > 0);

  return byte;
  ```
- Using an `unsigned char` for indexing is questionable. In any case it doesn't buy you much against a native `int`.
- A boolean expression as `+` operand may raise some eyebrows (`true` is guaranteed to be a non-zero in an arithmetic context, but it is not guaranteed to be 1). I recommend to force an arithmetic value by right-shifting `source` instead of left-shifting the mask:

  ```
  for(i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++) {
      byte[i] = '0' + (source & 1);
      source >>= 1;
  }
  ```
- You do not null-terminate the resulting string. The fact that your test succeeded is a sheer (un)luck.
- You probably know that returning static makes the code non-reentrant and thread-unsafe. You may want to let client provide a space for a resulting string.

Comment: I don´t think I need to null-terminated with the use of `static`, which will automatically enzero all the bytes. Everything other than that seems fairly legal.

Comment: It will "enzero" CHAR_BIT bytes (and we will overwrite them at the very first call anywhay). What happens with the next byte beyond the array (where a terminator is to be expected), which is not under your control?

Comment: It will be NULL, because `static` in most modern compilers ensures the buddy-memory fragments too. Make a test, but with gcc compiler and with std=c99

Comment: As I said, it will be NULL until somebody else (who claimed that byte) wrote something there.

Comment: Yes.. true that true.

Comment: @Genis: 1- consider using the big-endian order for bits: `for (i=CHAR_BIT; i--> 0; ) { bits[i] = '0' + (source & 1); source >>= 1; }` i.e., `'A'` is `"01000001"`, not `"10000010"` (though it depends on what you are doing with the bits). 2- the number of bytes is fixed and small typically. You could use a global `byte2bits[UCHAR_MAX+1][CHAR_BIT]` array and initialize it using: `for (size_t byte = 0; byte <= UCHAR_MAX; ++byte) 
      for (size_t position = 0; position < CHAR_BIT; ++position)  
        byte2bits[byte][CHAR_BIT-1-position] = '0' + ((byte >> position) & 1);
`